# Livepatch Behaviour and restart in

Tags: reboot, canonical-livepatch

I have installed livepatch on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Livepatch status indicates that patches have been applied (✓ all applicable livepatch modules inserted) but it asks me to reboot when I login via SSH :
*** Livepatch has fixed kernel vulnerabilities. System restart recommended on the closest maintenance window ***

I have rebooted several times but the message is still present. Is this a normal behaviour or I am missing something?

Comment: Well, it's clearly not normal for the Message Of The Day (motd) to keep demanding a reboot. However, it might not be a critical problem either. Look for critical problems the proper way: Check your syslog and journalctl for screaming error messages. If you want to go deeper into troubleshooting, check out the scripts in /etc/update-motd that build that login message. Under certain circumstances, those scripts can generate misleading or spurious messages. If you discover a reproducible bug, please file a bug report.

Comment: It seems that the kernel was not upgraded to the latest version. I just did apt update && apt upgrade and rebooted. The reboot message is now gone and the livepatch status indicate that no patches needed. It should fix my issue hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the repeating `System restart recommended on the closest maintenance window` message open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
```