# Stop livepatch notification at login

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Every time I log in to my laptop remotely, I get a message telling me to restart immediately because Livepatch has patched vulnerabilities:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-84-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

*** Livepatch has fixed kernel vulnerabilities. System restart recommended on the closest maintenance window ***
```

This is after I have restarted the machine.

How can I prevent this message from appearing every time on login?

I have followed the response given here to ensure all packages are updated: [Livepatch Behaviour and restart in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411986/livepatch-behaviour-and-restart-in), but still get the message on remote login.

I am not running the latest version of the kernel as it causes issues with the graphics: [Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS GUI does not work with 5.15.0-88-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492364/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-gui-does-not-work-with-5-15-0-88-generic)

EDIT: I also get the notification on login to the GUI that "Livepatch: An update has just been applied.", every time.

EDIT: I checked the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d`, and have the following:

```
.@.:/etc/update-motd.d$ sudo /snap/bin/canonical-livepatch  refresh
[sudo] password for .:
checking for patches
nothing to apply
kernel: 5.15.0-84.93-generic
patch state: ✓ all applicable livepatch modules inserted
patch version: 99.1
.@.:/etc/update-motd.d$ sudo /snap/bin/canonical-livepatch status
last check: 8 seconds ago
kernel: 5.15.0-84.93-generic
server check-in: succeeded
kernel state: ✓ kernel series 5.15 is covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ all applicable livepatch modules inserted
patch version: 99.1
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
machine id: 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue - booted the machine into the latest version of the kernel (now 5.15.0-89-generic), and logged in and updated to the latest packages via SSH (as the GUI is not working properly)